# Wifi disappeared on Raspberry pi 3 with overheat under no load

Tags: networking, wifi, internet, temperature

I have two raspberry Pi 3 with built in wifi card. I run a program that required internet on one of them the whole night last night. The next day, I say the red temperature gauge indicating an overheat and the program was disconnected from the internet. I stopped the pi immediately and let it cool for two hours. Then when I rebooted, the wifi card was not detected anymore, even when I run the `ifconfig` -a cmd. wlan0 just disappeared. In addition, the temperature started to increase very fast from 50 to 70 although I don't run any program on the pi.

To check if it was a software problem, I swapped the SD card of my pi to the other Raspberry pi that was healthy. The healthy pi detected its wifi card without any problem with no heat jump.

Is it a hardware fail? If so, is it possible remove the wifi card if it causes the fast increase in temperature so that I can at least use my pi with an external wifi usb dongle?
Also, how can I prevent that problem next time? How to tell the pi to turn off immediately when it reaches a certain temperature?

Thanks

Comment: You're not running any program on the pi, but something could still be revving it up.  Have you checked the CPU load when this is happening?

Comment: The CPU usage is 0.5 percent

Comment: That's probably a junk board now.  If you weren't overclocking it, you should look into getting a warranty replacement (usually 1 year).  The wifi chip could just as well be a victim as the culprit, so I would not get hung up on that as a cause unless you have more reason than the coincidence described here.  WRT to turning off when it overheats, I believe it should, but to be extra careful you could run a script polling `vcgencmd measure_temp` every minute or so.

Comment: I ran vcgencmd measure_temp every second

Comment: So why are you asking *"How to tell the pi to turn off immediately when it reaches a certain temperature?"* if you already know 1) How to get the current temperature, 2) How to shut down the pi.  I'm assuming #2 ;)

Comment: Which temperature threshold shouldn't it surpass normally?